# Passing data between C# and Java Apps

Tags: java, c#, file-upload, asyncsocket, message-passing

I have an API in C# .Net for uploading files whose size vary between 10 B - 100 KB. Per second, the system receives around 5 such calls. Now I want to pass this file to a JAVA process (Because it is a producer of Kafka, and we want it to be JVM based, while C# API is legacy). Both are going to reside on the same machine almost always. What is the best way of doing that?

I read about jni4net, IKVM for interacting with Java from C#. Would they be better or should I make it socket based (Web API in Java accepting the files), or should I read from the local filesystem where C# App has uploaded or any other option that I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In environment with high concurrency, reading from the local file-system might not be good idea.

You could use memory mapped files which java supports with FileChannel.

Depending on operating system, you could also use Named pipes for IPC, here is an article showing how to use pipes between .Net and Java:

http://v01ver-howto.blogspot.com/2010/04/howto-use-named-pipes-to-communicate.html

All options considered, i would go with sockets. They are portable and easy to do and will most likely meet performance requirements you have.

Answer (score 1):

You may also use a message queue. You can either put a binary message, serialize the file or put the location of file on the queue if you are storing the files in the file system.

A solution with sockets and message queues will allow you to have a more distributed architecture i.e. not loading a single machine with too much work.

Comment: The API call itself is behind the load balancer. So, I'd need a queue that would be able to pass log files as message to Java Application from .NET Application on the same machine. Which queue implementation would you suggest here?

Comment: I would suggest MSMQ. You may also find this question and answers to it useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12580230/sending-files-over-msmq

Comment: and because it's windows only you will need a 3rd party api to make use of it in java https://msmqjava.codeplex.com/

Answer (score -1):

If you want to actually use the C# API from Java, a bridge is probably the way to go.  It'll likely be more efficient than a Web API.  Some bridges will also allow you to run the C# and the Java in the same process, which is more efficient still.

In addition to the bridges you mention, you might want to consider JNBridgePro.  You can find more information at our website.

Disclosure -- I am affiliated with JNBridge.